# What triggers the release of 'managed' pci resources?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

If a driver calls `pcim_enable_device()`, then uses `pcim_iomap()`, `devm_request_irq()`, and other managed calls to allocate hardware resources, how does a driver tell the kernel to release those resources?

`pcim_release` isn't an exported symbol, so something else must cause `devres_free()` to be called.  But what?

Note: I don't need directions on how to release resources manually.  I want to know how to get the `devres` subsystem to release everything.  That's what it's for, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pcim_release()` becomes the `release` callback of the `struct devres`. The `release` callback is called in `release_nodes()` via `devres_release_all()`, which is called from a few places, notably `driver_detach()`.

In short I think you're not meant to worry about it, after all that's the whole point of `devres` - it manages resources for you, you don't have to worry about the cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want: pcim_iounmap

Comment: I should have been clearer.  I do other things other than just iomap; the mananged subsystem should release all of them at once.  pcim_iounmap will only release them one at a time.